# Why does a space make a difference in this code, in F#

Tags: f#

I have this type:

```
type ClockEvent (name: string, interval: TimeSpan, callback: unit -> unit) =
    ...
    member this.Start () =
       ...
```

and I use it like this:

```
ClockEvent("autowrite", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), fun _ ->
    match databaseWriterAsync connectionString |> Async.RunSynchronously with
    | Ok _    -> ()
    | Error e -> error $"couldn't write to the candles and kwap to the database: {e.Describe()}"
).Start()
```

which works as expected.

But if I add a space between 'ClockEvent' and '(', I get:

```
ClockEvent ("autowrite", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), fun _ ->
    match databaseWriterAsync connectionString |> Async.RunSynchronously with
    | Ok _    -> ()
    | Error e -> error $"couldn't write to the candles and kwap to the database: {e.Describe()}"
).Start()
```

and, suddenly:

```
Writer.fs(54, 20): [FS0597] Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized
```

I understand that the issue is linked to the '.Start()' at the end, but I don't get how the space causes the compiler to interpret the code differently.

Comment: 15.2 High precedence application https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a bit more context, the tricky thing is that there is a subtle difference in F# between function application and method calls.

In principle, you can write them both with and without spaces:

```
foo(14)  // Function call, but odd syntax with parentheses
foo (14) // The same, but now without space
foo 14   // This is how you typically write it
```

The same with method calls, but here the convention is different:

```
"abc".IndexOf('b') // Normal way of writing it
"abc".IndexOf 'b'  // You are allowed to have a space
"abc".IndexOf 'b'  // Parentheses around the 'a' expression
```

The problem with spaces is that F# generally requires you to parenthesize things:

```
foo (bar 1 (qux 2 3))
```

If you had to do this with method calls (this was the case in ancient versions of F#), it would be very tedious:

```
("foo".Substring(1)).Equals("oo") // This looks ugly
("foo".Substring 1).Equals "oo"   // But you can have spaces
```

So, the special high-precedence application rule says that if you do not have spaces (it looks like a method call), you are not required to write parentheses:

```
"foo".Substring(1).Equals("oo") // Works thanks to high-precedence rule
```

Comment: in my case, I was instantiating a type (ClockEvent), I guess that falls under method call, right?

Comment: @Thomas - Yeah, constructor call is actually another in-between thing :-). But the rule actually applies to everything - even ordinary function callls. So, you can write `sqrt(2).ToString()` rather than `(sqrt 2).ToString()` too.